# Cordova JQuery ajax not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to implement some ajax function on my cordova app(CLI 6.3.1) running on visaul studio 2017.It can properly run on the emulator.But when I install to mobile phone it return a connection error.

I have already include **CSP** like this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
        cache: true,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://10.0.1.28:80/exhibition_server/exhibition/search_exhibition.php",
        data: $("#searchExhibition").serialize(),
        async: false,
        error: function (request) {
            alert("Connection error");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            imgListener();
        }
    })
```

AJAX request always end up **Connection error**.

**Are there new requirement\setup for network request in Cordova 6.3.1, or anything else that can make this work?**

Thank you for your patient and consideration in advanced. -- Alverson

Comment: Shouldn't the version running on a mobile connect to a running server? Presumably, the mobile itself is not running an HTTP server on port 80 so your `http://localhost/...` isn't going to connect to anything

Comment: Sorry, I forget to change the url http://10.0.1.28:80/.., but it still occur the same issue.

Comment: Is the phone on the same network as your HTTP server? Can you reach `http://10.0.1.28` in the phone's browser?

Comment: Yes, it connect to the same AP. The url can be visit on the mobile browser, but not on the Cordova app.

Comment: Also, instead of throwing away any useful information from the error, how about `error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown) }`

Comment: As I add your code, alert show "error: SecurityError: Fail to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest':Refused to connect to 'http://10.0.1.28/...' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy".

Comment: If installed on Android phone, you can connect to pc and debug via Chrome browser on pc entering 'chrome://inspect' as url. There you will find what's wrong.

Comment: You also need this capability in config.xml for local network: <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />

Answer (score 0):

You have to send data using object format with some param name because you are using POST method.

```
data: {
  my_param:"my text as I want"
}
```

This will work

```
$.ajax({
        cache: true,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://10.0.1.28:80/exhibition_server/exhibition/search_exhibition.php",
        data: {
           use_anyname : $("#searchExhibition").serialize()
        },
        error: function (request) {
            alert("Connection error");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            imgListener();
        }
    })
```